# Create javascript function with JQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm getting JSon data from my server and building a table with this data. The last column of the table is a button that will grab the fields from the selected row to populate another fields, but it is returning: ReferenceError: response.DATA is not defined.

```
response = JSON.parse(response);

    $('.myDiv').empty();
    // Header
    var table = '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>ZIP</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<response.ROWCOUNT; i++){
      table += '<tr>';
      table += '<td>' + response.DATA.PROVIDERFIRSTNAME[i] + '</td>';
      table += '<td>' + response.DATA.PROVIDERLASTNAME[i] + '</td>';
      table += '<td>' + response.DATA.PROVIDERCITY[i] + '</td>';
      table += '<td>' + response.DATA.PROVIDERSTATE[i] + '</td>';
      table += '<td>' + response.DATA.PROVIDERPOSTALCODE[i] + '</td>';
      table += '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="select" onClick="setData(response.DATA, i);" /></td>';
      table += '</tr>';
    }
    table += '</tbody></table>';
    $('.myDiv').append(table);
```

My setData function:

```
function setData(data, pos){
    console.debug(data.PROVIDERFIRTNAME[pos]);
}
```

Comment: Why should `response.DATA` be defined? `response` is populated by parsing whatever `response` previously held as JSON, but we've no idea what that is.

Comment: What is the value of `response` when you log it?

Comment: I'm betting you are trying to read your array inside out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an inline handler, and an inline handler can only reference global variables. Attach the listener properly using Javascript instead, so that it can reference the variables (most importantly, `response` and `i`) properly. Also make sure `i` is block scoped with `let`, rather than function-scoped.

You can also consider using template literals to make the code a lot more readable:

```
// Header
const $table = $('<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>ZIP</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>');

// make sure to use "let i" here
for (let i = 0; i < response.ROWCOUNT; i++) {
  const $row = $(`
    <tr>
      <td>${response.DATA.PROVIDERFIRSTNAME[i]}</td>
      <td>${response.DATA.PROVIDERLASTNAME[i]}</td>
      <td>${response.DATA.PROVIDERCITY[i]}</td>
      <td>${response.DATA.PROVIDERSTATE[i]}</td>
      <td>${response.DATA.PROVIDERPOSTALCODE[i]}</td>
      <td>${response.DATA.PROVIDERPOSTALCODE[i]}</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="select"/></td>
    </tr>
  `);
  $row.find('input').on('click', () => {
    console.debug(response.DATA.PROVIDERFIRSTNAME[i]);
  });
  $table.find('tbody').append($row);
}
$('.myDiv').append(table);
```

Spelling matters - make sure to use `PROVIDERFIRSTNAME` instead of  `PROVIDERFIRTNAME`.

Inline handlers are pretty universally considered to be poor practice - best to avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! Just change to $('.myDiv').append($table); Could you please explain how the $varible = $('') works?

Comment: That creates the element and its innerHTML, and puts it all into a jQuery collection, allowing you to use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: Cool. Thank you!